# ¿Como puedo resolver este error del session_start() php?

Tags: php, hosting

Tengo un proyecto de php en la que hay un login y uso el session_start(), mi proyecto funciona bien en localhost y en GoDaddy pero en IONOS me sale este al momento de iniciar sesion:

PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /homepages/43/d886001790/htdocs/PHP_MVC/classes/session.php on line 9

```
class Session {

    private $sessionName = 'user';

    public function __construct(){
        if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
            session_start();
        }
    }

    public function setCurrentUser($user){
        $_SESSION[$this->sessionName] = $user;
    }

    public function getCurrentUser(){
        return $_SESSION[$this->sessionName];
    }

    public function closeSession(){
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function exists(){
        return isset($_SESSION[$this->sessionName]);
    }
}
```

He probado configurando el php.ini la directiva "display_errors" en off pero aun asi no se soluciono. Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error se genera porque `session_start()` debe ejecutarse antes de que ninguna otra cosa genere algún tipo de output, por ejemplo, un `echo` o código HTML. Esto puede producirse por varias razones que deberás investigar, pero puede deberse a un error anterior, a un script incluido con anterioridad que está generando algún output, etc. Lo importante a saber es que la función debe ser de las primeras cosas en ejecutarse.

Comment: la cosa es que funciona en GoDaddy y en localhost, pero no en ionos

Comment: Si la implementación es idéntica, igualmente, debe haber alguna diferencia entre uno y otro. Por ejemplo, chequea que las versiones de PHP no sean muy diferentes, y que por eso no se esté generando un error antes de ejecutar la función. El error reportado indica ese problema: algo pasó antes de enviar los encabezados.